# connect values with the same key in Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to combine 2 dictionary. they have the same key (**KKK**) with different values:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic1 = ...Load***();
Dictionary<string, string> dic2 = ...Load***();
```

dic1:

```
...
[29] {[RCP, 555501001]}
[30] {[KKK, 04611105012042000120]}
...
```

dic2:

```
...
[49] {[SUM, 85737]}
[50] {[KKK, 04611701040040000180]}
...
```

Union:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dicUnion= dic1.Union(dic2).OrderBy(k => k.Key).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

result:

```
ThrowArgumentException: The item with the same key has already been added.
```

I have connect values with the same key in union **Dictionary**:

```
...
[29] {[RCP, "555501001"]}
[30] {[KKK, "04611105012042000120 04611701040040000180"]}
[31] {[SUM, "85737"]}
...
```

Comment: Did you try [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use LINQ in this case(i'd prefer a loop):

```
var dicUnion = dic1.Concat(dic2)
    .GroupBy(kv => kv.Key)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => String.Join(" ", g.Select(kv => kv.Value)));
```

This will merge both dictionaries but don't care about common keys or different values.

> I need to combine 2 dictionary, they have the same key (KKK) with
>   different values

Ok, if you only want to create a dictionary of common keys:

```
var union = from kv1 in dic1
            join kv2 in dic2
            on kv1.Key equals kv2.Key into keyGroup
            where keyGroup.Any()
            select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kv1.Key, string.Join(" ", keyGroup.Select(kv => kv.Value)));

Dictionary<string, string> dicUnion = union.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

---

But instead of concatenating values which have the same key in both dictionaries, i'd use a different approach. Use a `Lookup<TKey, TValue>`. For example:

```
var keyLookup = dic1.Concat(dic2).ToLookup(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

Now you can do wahtever you want with the values, f.e. create a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> values = keyLookup["KKK"].ToList();
```

Comment: if equal keys and values?

Comment: @Denisrepon: Yes, what's then? Your question doesn't mention this case or what should happen then. My approach will concat them

Comment: @TimSchmelter, ok. thanks! I'll try to put the condition in join

Comment: @Denisrepon: what condition, what join?

Comment: @TimSchmelter  
 dic1.Where(x => dic2.ContainsKey(x.Key) && !dic2.ContainsValue(x.Value)).Select(...)..

Comment: @Denisrepon: i have edited my answer to show you an (efficient) approach where only common keys are added

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a simple loop to add / append items

```
Dictionary<string, string> dicUnion = new Dictionary<string, string>(dic1); 
foreach(var item in dic2)
{
    if(dicUnion.ContainsKey(item.Key))
    {
        dicUnion[item.Key] += " " + item.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        dicUnion.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe change to `dicUnion[item.Key] = (dicUnion[item.Key]  ?? "" +  " " + item.Value).Trim();` to avoid problems if the value stored is `null`

Answer (score 1):

Just try like this;

```
        var intersectedItems = dic1.Where(x => dic2.ContainsKey(x.Key)).Select(x => new
        {
            Key = x.Key,
            Value = x.Value + " " + dic2[x.Key]
        }).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
        var dicUnion = dic1.Where(x => !intersectedItems.ContainsKey(x.Key))
            .Union(dic2.Where(x => !intersectedItems.ContainsKey(x.Key)))
            .Union(intersectedItems).OrderBy(k => k.Key)
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: Is this readable or efficient? Nope. It's just a good example that LINQ sometimes hurts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect ONLY values with the same key, you can use `IEnumerable.Join` method like this:

```
var res = dic1.Join(dic2, o1 => o1.Key, o2 => o2.Key, (o1, o2) => new { o1.Key, Value1 = o1.Value, Value2 = o2.Value});
```

The arguments are the second `IEnumerable`, key selectors and result selector. In my snippet I create anonymous class but you can create whatever structure you want. The result is again `IEnumerable`, you can either iterate on or use its `ToList()`, `ToArray()`, etc method.

EDIT: after reading comments to other posts I understand you want to get something like this:

```
dic1.Concat(dic2)
    .ToLookup(o => o.Key, o => o.Value)
    .ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => string.Join(" ", o.Distinct()))
```